# C++, overloding functions, templates

Tags: c++, templates

I want to ask is it possible to write overloaded function for arithmetic's type which returns double and for containers (array, vector, valarray, etc...) which returns valarray. Simple example

```
template<typename T> 
double foo(T x) { 
  return x; 
}
 
template<typename T> 
std::valarray<double> foo(T const &arr) {
  std::valarray<double> valarr(1,1); 
  return valarr; 
}
```

In result I get expected message: call to 'foo' is ambiguous. Is there any possibility to write such a functions?

I would really appreciate all comments.

Comment: The reason it's ambiguous is that the compiler can't tell that you intend the second implementation's argument to be an array type.

Comment: @user888379 Yes, I know that and I'm not asking about that. My question is: How can it be written correctly

Comment: Fair enough - I saw that @Jarod42 had already provided a good answer, but I wanted to make sure you understood the nuances of the compiler message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::enable_if` to do what you want as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <valarray>

//overload for arthemtic types
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, double> foo(T x)
{
    std::cout<<"arithmetic version"<<std::endl;
    return x;
}
//overload for array
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::valarray<double> foo(T const (&arr)[N])
{
    std::valarray<double> valarr(2,5); 
    std::cout<<"array version"<<std::endl;
    return valarr;
}

//overload for non-arthemtic types
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T> foo(T x) //note the "!" in this version
{
    std::cout<<"non-arithmetic version"<<std::endl;
    return x;
}
int main() {
  int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
    foo(arr);//uses array version
    foo(5); //uses arithmetic version
    int p= 0, *c = &p;
    
    foo("string");//uses array version
    foo(p);//uses arithmetic version
    foo(c); //uses non-arithmetic version
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KZYepDeKzNrbtceQ).

Comment: Could I ask why that error occurred in previous version? It was a conflict between first and which function?

Comment: @Wywana It was the conflict between the primary template(the very first version) and the arithmetic version. Also, you can easily solve that by just creating another version for all types other than arithmetic types. For example, you can write another version as: `template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, T> foo(T x)
{
    std::cout<<"non-arithmetic version"<<std::endl;
    return x;
}`  **Note** the `!` in the above version. This will be choosen for all non-arithmetic versions. I have added it in my edited answer now. You can check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++20 *concepts*:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T> 
  requires std::is_arithmetic_v<T>
double foo(T x) { 
  return x; 
}

template<std::ranges::random_access_range T>
  requires std::is_arithmetic_v<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>
std::valarray<double> 
foo(T const& arr) {
  std::valarray<double> valarr(1,1); 
  return valarr; 
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/E1n4hb8c4)

Answer (score 1):

For C-array types, it would be:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::valarray<double> foo(T const (&arr)[N])
{
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xEcjj7zvY)

Comment: Thanks for answer :).  I would like to write it more general, for types such as: array, valarray, vector, etc..

Comment: So the only way in C++17 and below is to write multiple overloaded functions for each type?

Comment: @Wywana: Most concept usages can be replaced by SFINAE, in a more verbose way.